# pandas df lookup value based on multiple conditions

Tags: pandas, python-3.6

my df called symbols looks like this:

```
                                   local_symbol            code globex expiry_date type  strike
symbol                                                                                         
OZN20121221P00014900_FOP  P OZN DEC 12    14900  CBT_21_F2013_S    OZN  2012-12-21    P   149.0
OZN20121221C00012500_FOP  C OZN DEC 12    12500  CBT_21_F2013_S    OZN  2012-12-21    C   125.0
OZN20121221P00012450_FOP  P OZN DEC 12    12450  CBT_21_F2013_S    OZN  2012-12-21    P   124.5
OZN20121221C00013900_FOP  C OZN DEC 12    13900  CBT_21_F2013_S    OZN  2012-12-21    C   139.0
OZN20121221C00010700_FOP  C OZN DEC 12    10700  CBT_21_F2013_S    OZN  2012-12-21    C   107.0
```

using pandas 0.22.0 the following worked:

```
exp_date = dt.date(2012, 12, 21)
code = 'CBT_21_F2013_S'
type = 'P'
strike = 124.5
symbols.loc[(symbols.expiry_date == exp_date)
            & (symbols.code == code)
            & (symbols.type == type)
            & (symbols.strike == strike)]
```

and returned OZN20121221P00012450_FOP as the expected value. In Pandas 0.23 i get an empty dataframe. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe problem with `expiry_date` column - not dates. What is `print (df['expiry_date'].head().apply('type'))` ?

Comment: ValueError: type is an unknown string function

Comment: sorry, `print (df['expiry_date'].head().apply(type))`

Comment: ValueError: P is an unknown string function. 
symbols.expiry_date is dtype: datetime64[ns]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need convert column `expiry_date` to `date`s and for compare floats use [`numpy.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html):

```
symbols.loc[(symbols.expiry_date.dt.date == exp_date)
            & (symbols.code == code)
            & (symbols.type == type)
            & np.isclose((symbols.strike, strike)]
```

Comment: still returns a empty df.

Comment: @steff - Check now please.

Comment: still empty df... sry

Comment: @steff - Can you check whitespaces?

Comment: are data confidental? Is possible send csv to my email in my profile? It looks some data problem.

Comment: Not confidential. Sent you

Comment: I sent email back, but `symbols.expiry_date.dt.date == exp_date` for me working nice :(